# Provide RDP Access to Server

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd.exe

Good day guys,
can you help me guys on give me an option for adding user on RDP from server to server,
kindly exclude psexec since it is block by our server

currently i have 100 server with 3 domain that is needed to add to the server i know that it will be faster if AD team will create an OU group for this request but what if i want to add it manually or by batch file or script remotely.

below i tried it work internally but how about when im on the other server?

```
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member $user - Working
```

but not sure how to use the below one

```
[ADSI]$account = WinNT://domain/username,User
```

Comment: What do you mean by this? ***but not sure how to use the below one*** ```[ADSI]$account = WinNT://domain/username,User``` --- are you saying it's not returning results? Using ADSI via Powershell is well documented on the MS Docs site and all over the web and in Youtube videos. It's been around for decades, well before PowerShell ever existed. It's how things were done using VBScript. What did you search for? Point of note, the way you have that command formatted is not valid for PowerShell. Again, many doc showing how-to's for it.

Comment: i have been trying to search for remotely added a user to another server but i think ive been searching it wrong my only goal is in another server instead of logging in or compmgmt.msc then connect to another computer why not use power shell you dont have to give me the answer but can you help me the what is the exact terminilogy of that?

Answer (score 0):

This, in PowerShell...

```
[ADSI]$account = WinNT://domain/username,User
```

...should be this.

```
$UserAccounts = [ADSI]("WinNT://$env:USERDOMAIN/$env:USERNAME")
```

... of course, change the details as needed.